# AZ Azure Commands fail: error: the following arguments are required: --name/-n, --resource-group/-g

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

Creating a resource in Azure with the following command:

```
az vm create --name quickvm --resource-group RG1 --image Debian --admin-username student --admin-password Password456#@long
```

Fails with:

> az vm create: error: the following arguments are required: --name/-n, --resource-group/-g

This isn't the first time, the commands are definitely correct, so something funny is going on. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the formatting of the hyphens is malformed. Type the hyphens in again or replace the big-endians:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Same happened to me during Azure Fundamentals course:

```
az vm extension set \
       --resource-group learn-....\
       --vm-name my-vm \
       -n customScript \
       --publisher Microsoft.Azure.Extensions \
       --version 2.1 \
       --settings '{"fileUris":["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft
       --protected-settings '{"commandToExecute": "./configure-nginx.sh"}'
```

> the following arguments are required: --name/-n, --publisher

Switching from **az interactive** to **bash** helped.

Replacing dashes or spaces or copying-pasting into text editor didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue but, It was maybe due to the ''   backslash: here
**the working line**

```
az vm create   --resource-group learn-35bcc4c7-0aff-4bb9-93c0-79291229b46b   --name my-vm   --image UbuntuLTS   --admin-username azureuser --generate-ssh-keys
```

**error line**

```
az vm create \
  --resource-group learn-35bcc4c7-0aff-4bb9-93c0-79291229b46b \
  --name my-vm \
  --image UbuntuLTS \
  --admin-username azureuser \
  --generate-ssh-keys
```